# Setting a property with a string value

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class Category with two a property name as string.

and have a other class that use this class.

```
Public Class Myclass
{
      public virtual Category Category
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

I have a object of Myclass. I want set string value for Category Property of this object .

```
Myclass cls=new Myclass();
cls.Category=// a string value
```

How to set this ?

Comment: I suggest you get a better clarification of the basics of class properties, methods, constructors etc. :) If you are interested, hope this [web post](http://www.dotnetperls.com/class) , [links](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/C-Sharp/Introduction-to-Objects-and-Classes-in-C-sharp/4/) helps going forward. You can search something which could give better understanding too.

Comment: The property called `Category` is of a type also called `Category`. But we don't know what this `Category` is? Is it a class or an enum, perhaps? We need to know that. Why do you think a `string` type should convert to `Category` type? Since `System.String` does not derive from (or implement) anything called `Category`, you will need an implicit conversion operator for it to work. Or simply call some method explicitly which converts your `string` into `Category`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, if one of those string properties is "Name" then you just set it like this:

```
Myclass cls=new Myclass();
cls.Category = new Category();
cls.Category.Name = "CategoryName1";
```

Note that the `Name` property must be *accessible* to the calling code (e.g. `public`).

Or you can write it like this:

```
Myclass cls=new Myclass();
cls.Category = new Category {Name = "CategoryName1"};
```

Comment: thanks a lot, if this Category with name "CategoryName1" is exist in Category list, it add again to Category list?

Comment: No, this will create a new Category object but will not add it to any lists. In other words, the list has no way to know that a new Category object has been created somewhere else in the program.

Answer (score 2):

From your example:

```
Public Class Myclass
{
      public virtual Category Category
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

I am thinking you mean this:

```
Public Class Myclass
{
      public string Category { get; set; } // variable
      public MyClass() {}  //<- empty constructor-might be created by default .. but I like to put them in
}
```

then call:

```
Myclass cls=new Myclass();
cls.Category= "text here";
```

It looks like your type for the `Category` variable is `Category` instead of string?

Unless you already have a Category type somewhere that you want to use.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but i want to have a category property to myclass.

Comment: This gives you a property called Category, but it needs a type of string.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you meant?

```
public class Category
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
}


Category myCategory = new Category();
myCategory.Category.Name = "Basketball";
myCategory.Category.Description = "Played Indoors";
```

**Tutorial Reference:** Below are some examples to help you understand properties and class's

[Tutorial 1](http://www.dotnetperls.com/property)

[Tutorial 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288470%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, but i want add property of category type to myclass.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set string value to non-string field. But if you need that string inside class instance, you can write like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public Category(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And then declare Category field of MyClass like this:

```
var cls = new MyClass();
cls.Category = new Category("hello");
```